# Power BI fonts that are compatable with a MAC

Tags: powerbi

I have amended my JSON file within my Power BI custom theme to have TT Commons and when viewing the dashboard on a window machine, the font is correct. However, when a MAC users sees the dashboard, the font is totally different.
Does anyone know how to make the font compatable for a MAC user, or knows the fonts which will work across a windows and MAC machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerBI handling of fonts is quite poor at the moment and will always depend on the fonts installed by the user. If you want something that is consistent across MAC and PC, stick to Verdana, Arial Black, Georgia etc.